# ASP.NET Web API 2 custom routing to specific method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

How can I configure routing in ASP.NET Web API to route it to specific method in controller with GET method?

http://mysite/healthcheck

Registration in WebAPiConfig looks like this:

```
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "HealthCheck",
        routeTemplate: "healthcheck",
        defaults: new { action =" DefaultAction" }
    );
```

The controller looks like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("healthcheck")]
public class HealthCheckController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("DefaultAction")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetHealthCheckStatus()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }    
}
```

I get Not Found instead of Ok when hitting that URL. Any help would be appreciated

**UPDATE**
Thank you for all the suggestions, I checked them all and none works. The route debugger shows no matches. I am putting this on hold for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Startup.cs` register attribute routes:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

And in the controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("healthcheck")]
public class HealthCheckController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route]
    public IHttpActionResult GetHealthCheckStatus()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it still does not work.

Comment: Did you remove the HealthCheck-route from the `HttpRouteCollection` ?

Comment: Do you mean "config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( name: "HealthCheck" ... ) ? Yes I did. It did not help

Comment: Ok, weird. Works here :I

Comment: After having a lunch break, it started working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Remove this in config

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "HealthCheck",
    routeTemplate: "healthcheck",
    defaults: new { action =" DefaultAction" }
);
```

and do this in controller

```
public class HealthCheckController : ApiController
{
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    [Route("healthcheck")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetHealthCheckStatus()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it did not help

Comment: There might be some problem with your configrations \

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it for web-api, but tested it for MVC, I think it should work the same.

In route registration you should ensure, that this route comes before the standard api route, because route order matters:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "HealthCheck",
            "healthcheck",
            new {Controller = "Default", action = "Index"}
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
    }
```

In the controller you may not prefix the controllers and action names, but to specify correct controller name and action name in the template:

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("I'm hit");
    }
}
```

If you still having problems, then you can read [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/) and enable route debugging too see which route is invoked and what are the params.

Comment: Probably there is something else wrong in your project that makes routing go wild. I would suggest you to create a small project and check if you can reproduce the issue you have described there. If yes - put it here, if no - check what's different in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are enabling attribute routing, you can specify the action as the default endpoint for the controller using `RoutePrefix` by using `[Route("")]` with empty route template.

```
[RoutePrefix("healthcheck")]
public class HealthCheckController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")] // Matches GET http://mysite/healthcheck
    public IHttpActionResult GetHealthCheckStatus() {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

With the above then there would be no need for the convention-based *HealthCheck* route from the OP. It can be removed safely from *WebApiConfig*